# The file was loaded in wrong encoding : UTF-8

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin

I was trying add a database file to my asset folder but when I add it shows this error I don't know what to do please help.
Do I need topo add any diapedesis in order use my .db file
I tried to change the encoding using notepad++ but no luck.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN0xW.png)

Comment: A SQLite database is a binary file and shouldn't be opened in a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually not a problem, as mentioned by @Shawn, Android Studio (at least without plugins, I think) cannot open the .db files, you can use something like [Db browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) to open up a .db file and modify it, BUT after importing (if you're sure that the file is not corrupted or anything) you can just use it with room